# How to change the contents of a methods in a new class

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm trying to change the transition direction of a change in screen through swiping but I have not been able to achieve such. The screen is changing but I want the directions of the change to be different. How to I do that?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < touch.ox:
            MainApp.get_running_app().change_screen(screen_name="swipedhikr_screen")
                #MainApp.get_running_app().screen_manager.transition.direction = "left" ----> also didn't work
```

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.transition.direction = "up"  # I also tried screen_direction = screen_manager.transition.direction
        # screen_direction = "up"
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def quit_app(self):
        MainApp().stop()


MainApp().run()
```

I have tried making `screen_manager.transition.direction` to be variable and then setting that variable to be "up" so that I can access that variable and manipulate it in my `class HomeScreen(Screen)` but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you can use `switch_to()`:

```py
    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager.switch_to(screen_name, direction='up')
```

See the documentation: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to

Comment: I want to be able to call change_screen to change to any screen so I can't hard code the name of the screen. I tried this:                                                                              
 ```class HomeScreen(Screen):
     def on_touch_move(self, touch):
         if touch.x < touch.ox:
             sm = ScreenChange()
             sm.switch_to("swipedhikr_screen", direction="right")
            
class ScreenChange(ScreenManager):
    pass```

Answer (score 0):

It works when I passed the direction as a parameter, so it becomes

```
def change_screen(self, screen_name, screen_direction):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]  
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        screen_manager.transition.direction = screen_direction
```